# Webassembly in rust executable binary

Tags: redis, rust, webassembly, wasm-bindgen

Is it possible to compile webassembly code in the executable?
What I mean by that is that you have an executable, which also serves some interface to javascript via webassembly.

Right now my project is separated into two, both written in Rust. One is the executable, which publishes all the information in Redis, that is being consumed by the wasm intermediary code into javascript to render it.

Is it possible to get rid of Redis altogether and just make an executable to have the wasm intermediary code?

Tried to find an information to this question, and so far only got the suggestion to transfer it to C, which then will be turned into executable.

Comment: You could compile two crates, the first one as a wasm binary, the second one as a native exe, and use `include_bytes!()` the former in the latter, would that work for you?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'll try that out. @rodrigo

Comment: Another suggestion is to use wasmer or wasmtime.